# Cordova never fires device ready

Tags: android, cordova

I created a new Cordova 4.0 project, added android platform and added all the core plugins and the following is my index.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>   <head>
    <title>Notification Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
           alert("ready");
    }

    // Show a custom alert
    //
    function showAlert() {
        navigator.notification.alert(
            'You are the winner!',  // message
            'Game Over',            // title
            'Done'                  // buttonName
        );
    }

    // Beep three times
    //
    function playBeep() {
        navigator.notification.beep(3);
    }

    // Vibrate for 2 seconds
    //
    function vibrate() {
        navigator.vibrate(2000);
    }

    </script>   </head>   <body>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="showAlert(); return false;">Show Alert</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="playBeep(); return false;">Play Beep</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="vibrate(); return false;">Vibrate</a></p>   </body> </html>
```

But I could never see the device ready firing. Any ideas on what is wrong with the abive snippet ?

Comment: change `src="/cordova.js"` to `src="cordova.js"`. Hope it works!

Comment: I removed all the plugins added, removed android platform , added it back and then added all the plugins back. Doesn't sound good, but it is working for now. I will try to reproduce it again with a new Cordova project. As of now vibrate and beep are working. The ready message on device ready is still not displayed and the showAlert function is still not working. I am not sure why device ready doesn't fire.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/cordova.js"></script>
```

to

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: Actually I used your suggestion initially and when it didn't work I changed to the one posted here. It still doesn't work .

Comment: you need to locate the `cordova.js` file. Is it available in the `<your_project_name>\platforms\android\assets\www` directory? How  have you created the cordova project?

Comment: cordova.js file is available in the location <your_project_name>\platforms\android\assets\www . I used Cordova cli and ran the create command to create the project.

Comment: Is your index.html in the www folder and did you use `cordova run android`?

Comment: Yes, index.html is in www folder and I used cordova run android to install and run the app on the device.

Comment: Maybe try to recreate the Cordova project and android project, when I test the situation on my local machine, it works. Also the alert messages shows on start up.